# Faster way to open multiple pics for HDR

Tags: adobe-photoshop

If I start makeing a HDR by file->automation->HDR add pics, I need a lot of time.
Can I make a action in bridge to open 3 pics for HDR with just one click? Batch process it, so calculations for the next pic are done in the background?